# compile error using boost asio in a wxwidget application

Tags: c++, boost, wxwidgets

I am trying to use boost::asio in a wxwidget application.

If I add boost::asio before wxwidget headers, I am not getting any error, but when I add boost::asio header after wxwidget header, I am getting error is this line (line 24) in file socket_types.hpp

```
 #  error WinSock.h has already been included
```

I know that I can include boost header before wxwidget and not getting this error, but in my code I need to include a header that uses boost::asio and wxwidget and I need to include this header after wxwidget, so I need to be able to include boost::asio after wxwidget.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `wxUSE_IPV6` to 1 in your `wx/msw/setup.h` file: enabling the use of IPv6 also enables the use of WinSock2 instead of ancient WinSock that ASIO complains about.

Notice that you need to recompile wxWidgets after making this change, of course.